# Sending data in a cookie to Google Analytics via javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

Can anybody help improve this copy/paste Frankenstein's monster of javascript I've put together?

I'm trying to retrieve specific data from a cookie, stitch it together, then send to Google Analytics as a User Id per https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666.

What I've got will work (I think), but is probably completely inefficient and likely has a bunch of redundancy.

The value of *cookiename* is:

```
"{\"number1\":123,\"number2\":456,\"otherthing\":null}"
```

What I'd like to set as the User Id is:

```
123.456
```

Challenges I've faced:

- Retrieving the value from a specific cookie.
- Removing escape characters and unnecessary quotes from the string so I can actually JSON.parse() it.
- Stitching *number1* and *number2* together with a period between.
- Returning that value from a function
- Sending to Google Analytics.

What I've ended up with:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function idmaker() {
    var cookievalue = decodeURI(getCookie("cookiename"));
    var tidiedcookievalue = cookievalue.replace(/\\/g, "").slice(1, -1);
    var parsedcookie = JSON.parse(tidiedcookievalue);
    var UID = parsedcookie.number1 + "." + parsedcookie.number2;
    return UID;
}

function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
}(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'auto');
ga('set', 'userId', idmaker());
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Please destroy me.